# What happened to Align Center Y and Align Center X? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, autolayout

I just updated Xcode to Version 7.0 and it appears that the autolayout has changed a bit.  One thing that changed is that "Align Center Y" and "Align Center X" no longer are options.  I used this frequently, and was helpful for aligning content with each other.

Is this option still available?  Here is the options available:
[image]

Comment: Center vertically is the same as Center y isn't it?  Center horizontally should appear also if you drag in the right direction.  You can also select an element and then go to the editor->align menu

Comment: @Paulw11, correct me if I am wrong, but Align Center Y and Align Center X aligned the object you are aligning with another object, were as Center Vertically and Center Horizontally center the object vertically and horizontally in the ViewController.

Comment: I wasn't sure which one you meant.  'Center vertically' on the pop-up menu is the new wording for 'center X' - it is relative to the other object you selected.  I guess the reference to "x" and "y" were somewhat arbitrary if you didn't know how the axes were designated while horizontal and vertical are absolute

Comment: I dont want to center y in the View Controller, I want to center y with another element..  So Center Vertically is the same thing as Align Center X?  I wish apple wouldnt constantly change autolayout.  Making my job difficult! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Center horizontally" is the new wording for "Center X" and "Center vertically" is the new wording for "Center Y".

The terms "X" and "Y" depend upon you knowing the convention for the naming of axes while "horizontal" and "vertical" are absolute.

Here I have ctrl-dragged from one label to another and selected "Center horizontally"

[image]

You can see that the center of the two labels is now linked.

Further, if you look at the constraint that was created you will see that it retains the old "center X" wording -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add objects to the storyboard, blue guides will appear when you are aligned with another object on the storyboard

[image]

Also, if you want to be vary precise with the position of an object and not use the size inspector, you can select the object, hold the option key, and use the arrows to move the object.

[image]

### Update:

I tried using the Align Horizontally

[image]

And this is what happened

[image]

So, I'm not sure I would want to use that.